# use request.POST without knowing the name and number of inputs

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Is there a way that become aware of name and value of inputs in request.POST?
I know i can access the value of inputs by knowing name of them like this:

```
name = request.POST['inputName']
```

but if i don't know how many inputs and with what names they are, what can i do? is there a way to loop through request.POST?
(i create my html with xsl, and because i'm creating html by parsing xml file, the number and nmame of inputs are variable. so i have to use this way)
really thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default iterator of Python dictionaries returns keys - what this means is that when you loop through a dictionary, it will return each key. Since `request.POST` is a "dict like" object, it works:

```
for i in request.POST:
   print 'I have been passed the following keys: ',i
```

You can also do:

```
print 'The total number of keys in my POST request: ', len(request.POST.keys())
```

Comment: Note that `request.POST` is not a normal Python dictionary, but a Django `QueryDict`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects (it can contain multiple values for each key -- but otherwise works as a dict)

Comment: Yes @vicvicvic hence the `dict like` in my answer.

Comment: Of course, I didn't mean to insinuate that you were incorrect in any way.

Answer (score -3):

Try to just foreach them. 
Example:

```
foreach(request.POST as item){
 print item;
}
```

Comment: This is PHP, the question is talking about Python.

Comment: Burhan Khalid: Nope, the $'s are missing ;)

Comment: Python doesn't have braces, semicolons, as, nor foreach. :P